# How can I connect to Office365 mail server using OAuth to send email?

Tags: emails

I am using SwiftMailer to connect to an Office365 email account. So all emails issued from the Drupal site are sent via the SMTP server on Office365.

However, from October 2022, Office365 will no longer authorise a connection using a username and password and will only allow connection via OAuth. But SwiftMailer doesn't have an option for OAuth and it's replacement Symphony Mailer doesn't appear to have one either.

Does anyone know how to connect to Office365 via OAuth to allow sending of emails?